# Problems with detecting mouseClick in a JPanel and preventing circle from painting in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

My current program lets the user move a circle around the JFrame and also change its color by pressing one of the colors presented in the JPanel at the bottom of the JFrame.

My code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class SixthProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GUI prog=new GUI("SixthProgram");
        prog.setBounds(350,250,500,250);
        prog.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class GUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    JButton button;
    JPanel colorPan, color1, color2, color3 ,color4 ,color5;
    Color color=Color.BLACK;

    int x=3,y=30;

    public GUI(String header)
    {
        super(header);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        maker();

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

        add(colorPan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void maker()
    {
        colorPan = new JPanel();

        Border raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Border loweredbevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedbevel, loweredbevel);
        colorPan.setBorder(compound);

        colorPan.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        color1 = new JPanel();
        color2 = new JPanel();
        color3 = new JPanel();
        color4 = new JPanel();
        color5 = new JPanel();

        color1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        color2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        color3.setBackground(Color.RED);
        color4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        color5.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        colorPan.add(color1);
        colorPan.add(color2);
        colorPan.add(color3);
        colorPan.add(color4);
        colorPan.add(color5);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        super.paint(g); //Do the same thing as above(Clear jframe)

        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) //MouseListener overrided methods
    {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {}

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Press");    
        if(e.getX()+50 < getWidth() && e.getY()+50 < getHeight()) // Preventing out of bounds
        {
            x=e.getX();
            y=e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) //Press+Release=Click
    {
        System.out.println("Click");
        if((e.getX()>=8 && e.getX()<=105) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
            color=Color.WHITE;
        else if((e.getX()>=106 && e.getX()<=203) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
            color=Color.GREEN;
        else if((e.getX()>=204 && e.getX()<=301) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
            color=Color.RED;
        else if((e.getX()>=302 && e.getX()<=399) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
            color=Color.BLUE;
        else if((e.getX()>=400 && e.getX()<=489) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
            color=Color.BLACK;
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) //MouseMotionListener overrided methods
    {
        System.out.println("Dragged to ("+ e.getX() +","+ e.getY() +")");
        if((e.getX()>=3 && e.getY()>=30) && (e.getX()+50<getWidth() && e.getY()+50<getHeight())) //If circle is dragged in the JFrame
        {
            x=e.getX();
            y=e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {}

}
```

The above code works as expected and produces the output:

[image: OUTPUT]

When I click the colors in the JPanel in the bottom too, the program works as expected and changes the color of the circle.

The two problems that appears are:

1. When I resize the JFrame, the color chooser doesn't work as expected. This is due to my stupid way of hardcoding in the `mouseClicked` method:

   ```
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) //Press+Release=Click
   {
       System.out.println("Click");
       if((e.getX()>=8 && e.getX()<=105) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
           color=Color.WHITE;
       else if((e.getX()>=106 && e.getX()<=203) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
           color=Color.GREEN;
       else if((e.getX()>=204 && e.getX()<=301) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
           color=Color.RED;
       else if((e.getX()>=302 && e.getX()<=399) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
           color=Color.BLUE;
       else if((e.getX()>=400 && e.getX()<=489) && (e.getY()>=232 && e.getY()<=243))
           color=Color.BLACK;
       repaint();
   }
   ```
2. The second problem is that the circle can be dragged onto the color chooser. I don't know what I should do in order to prevent this. I could hardcode the values just like I did for problem #1, but this will create the same issue as problem #1.

I would prefer not to use `setResizable(false)` and that the JFrame to be resizeable.

How do I fix the mentioned problems?

Comment: If you use JButtons for your colors instead of drawing them directly, that should alleviate both problems

Comment: There's a package in my open source project for moving shapes around in a Component, would you be interested in that, or is this something you'd rather solve yourself for fun?

Comment: @ControlAltDel , Thanks. I've replaced those `JPanels` with `JButtons`. And I'm doing this for fun, for improving my skills in swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just re implemented your problem in a better way. Here is how it looks like now: Problems are solved.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CirclePainter implements MouseMotionListener, ActionListener {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel colorPanel, circlePanel;
    private JButton whiteColorButton, redColorButton, greenColorButton,
            blueColorButton;

    private int circleWidth = 3, circleHeight = 15;
    private Color circleColor = Color.black;

    public CirclePainter() {
        initGui();
    }

    public void initGui() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Circle");
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 400);

        colorPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        whiteColorButton = new JButton();
        whiteColorButton.setBackground(Color.white);
        whiteColorButton.setActionCommand("white");
        whiteColorButton.addActionListener(this);
        redColorButton = new JButton();
        redColorButton.setBackground(Color.red);
        redColorButton.setActionCommand("red");
        redColorButton.addActionListener(this);
        greenColorButton = new JButton();
        greenColorButton.setBackground(Color.green);
        greenColorButton.setActionCommand("green");
        greenColorButton.addActionListener(this);
        blueColorButton = new JButton();
        blueColorButton.setBackground(Color.blue);
        blueColorButton.setActionCommand("blue");
        blueColorButton.addActionListener(this);

        colorPanel.add(whiteColorButton);
        colorPanel.add(redColorButton);
        colorPanel.add(greenColorButton);
        colorPanel.add(blueColorButton);

        circlePanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(circleColor);
                g.fillOval(circleWidth, circleHeight, 50, 50);
            }
        };
        circlePanel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        circlePanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        mainFrame.add(circlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainFrame.add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "white":
            circleColor = Color.white;
            circlePanel.repaint();
            break;
        case "red":
            circleColor = Color.red;
            circlePanel.repaint();
            break;
        case "green":
            circleColor = Color.green;
            circlePanel.repaint();
            break;
        case "blue":
            circleColor = Color.blue;
            circlePanel.repaint();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CirclePainter();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if ((e.getX() >= 0 && e.getY() >= 0)
                && (e.getX() <= mainFrame.getWidth() - 60)
                && (e.getY() <= mainFrame.getHeight() - 110)) {
            circleWidth = e.getX();
            circleHeight = e.getY();
            circlePanel.repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for converting my program. `circleWidth` and `circleHeight` are confusing names as they denote the position of the circle, not the width and height. I have some questions: Why use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`? The program works the same way when I remove it too. How did you get `110` and `60` in `(e.getY() <= mainFrame.getHeight() - 110)` and `(e.getX() <= mainFrame.getWidth() - 60)` and what do they denote?

Comment: Sorry for bad names i didn't noticed that.
I used SwingUtilities.InvokeLater because the Swing data structures aren't thread-safe, so to provide programmers with an easily-achievable way of preventing concurrent access to them it is used. It will run the piece of code on the AWT thread. Which lets you modify the GUI from other threads. Also your program dragged the ball behind color panel so i restricted it by just adding this restriction: (e.getY() <= mainFrame.getHeight() - 110)
same goes with the width.

Answer (score 3):

You should NOT override the paint() method of a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then you add the panel to the frame. You would add this panel to the frame using `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

For your colors you should create a separate panel and add buttons to the panel to represent each color. You would set the background of each button to the specific color. You could use a GridLayout. Then you add this panel to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` of the frame.

Then, instead of using a MouseListener you would add an `ActionListener` to each button. The basic code would be:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    color = button.getBackground();
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. BTW, nice way of getting the color from `actionPerformed`.